# converting recursive function to arrow function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

How can i convert following function to arrow function? I am using currying here

```
function mergeString(str){
   return function(str1){
     if(str1){
        return mergeString(str + ' ' + str1); 
     }
     else
     {
       return str;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you *want* to use an arrow function here? No good reason to use one.

Comment: Notice that the term "currying" only applies to functions of fixed arity. For varargs functions it's really hard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could chain the function heads and then the function body for all.

```js
const mergeString = str => str1 => str1 ? mergeString(str + ' ' + str1) : str;

console.log(mergeString('a')());
console.log(mergeString('a')('b')('c')());
console.log(mergeString('this')('should')('work')('as')('well')());
```

Comment: Very nice, but what about `mergeString() // => ""` ?

Comment: that need a different ignature of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Actuall this is a good usecase for rest parameters:

```
 const mergeStrings = (...strings) => strings.join(" ");
```

Usable as:

```
mergeString(
  "one",
  "two",
  "three"
)
```

Comment: @nishant just wanted to show some alternative ways to write this :)